# Strange occurrence with XPath expression when using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have an html file with two tables and I am using HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument to retrieve the data.

I tried using

```
htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[2]/tr")
```

to access the rows of the second table but I get null value. If I do

```
htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[1]/tr")
```

I get the rows of the first table just fine.

I know it does see a second table because if I try

```
htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")
```

I get count of 2

But if I do:

```
 if (htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table") != null)
               {
                   if (htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").Count == 2)
                   {
                       var table = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")[1];
                       foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes(".//tr"))
                       {

                       }
                   }
               }
```

Then I get the rows of the second table.

My question is why I could not get the correct table in one XPath expression:

```
htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[1]/tr")
```

Comment: provide an HTML snippet we can test with.
Maybe it's javascript that fill second table so there is no rows there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that's because each `table` resides in different parent element. In this case, `//table[2]` will match each `table` element that is the 2nd table in the corresponding parent element, for example :

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <table>ignored</table>
        <table>this will be selected</table>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <table>ignored</table>
        <table>this will be selected</table>
    </parent>
</root>
```

To select the 2nd table in the whole document, you need to wrap the table selector in brackets before applying the index :

```
(//table)[2]/tr
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester.com demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/1b1af2b47672111e14a4e6e0fefc18e4)</kbd>**